# Assumptions of GLM with negative binomial error distribution and categorical independent

Tags: generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, biostatistics, assumptions, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm carrying out a study comparing the abundance of a few species between two treatment groups. I have carried out an NMS analysis to compare overall community composition and structure, but I also want to compare the abundance of each individual species.

I'm using a GLM in R with family = negative binomial and link = log. The AIC for the models range between 100-200 and the dispersion parameter is between 1-2.

I want to check the assumptions of my model but I don't know how. I was taught to do it using the plot(model) function, but when using a categorical X variable the plots make no sense to me (see below). The quantile-quantile plot looks good, but the others I don't get.
Can anyone interpret these graphs for me or suggest a better way to test the assumptions of my model?

[image: Residuals vs fitted]

[image: Q-Q plot]

[image: Scale-Location plot]

[image: Constant leverage plot]

Comment: Try using the R `DHARMa` package. The standard `plot` function is not very helpful for non-Gaussian GLMS. See the vignette here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html

Comment: What assumptions do you want to check?  What does "NMS" stand for?  Do you only have a single explanatory variable that is binary?

Comment: "NMS" probably means "nonmetric multidimensional scaling" ?